# How can i change the directory in this VBA code? VBA "Excel to TXT or CSV"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

I really want to change the directory of this code in `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` but i don't know where to put it.

```
Public Sub CharacterSV()
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells, _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

I tried to figure it out, and really want to learn VBA, but i couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the inspiration.

I just passed by another code that made it way more easy.
Cause i just wanted to add the file in the directory were i'm working from, but wanted to make the vba dynamic.

So i used `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.
I also added the name from the sheet to it in `" - " & ActiveSheet.Name &`

This is the final code (also added name of sheet):

```
Public Sub Worksheet_naar_TXT_Pipe_delimiter()
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open ActiveWorkbook.FullName & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells, _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

Thanks for your response, this brought me to the idea!

Comment: It's proper to upvote and mark the answer that helped you as "correct" to give the answerer thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:
`Dim fname as string
fname = "c:\documents and settings\desktop\"
Open fname & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".txt" For Output As #nFileNum`

Replace desktop with your directory and the open will open the new file in your directory, take care to write a real and correct path in fname.